# Fluent nhibernate query where nullable int

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I have a class similar like this:

```
public class WorkEntity
{
    ... // other stuff here
    public virtual int? WorkTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

in my joined queryover I need to filter my results by WorkTypeID

```
query.Where(() => workEntity.WorkTypeID == filter.WorkTypeID.Value);
```

it doesn't work, because the type is nullable, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
query.Where(() => workEntity.WorkTypeID != null && workEntity.WorkTypeID.Value == filter.WorkTypeID.Value);
```

Comment: Also add filter.WorkTypeID != null to the add condition if that could be a case too.