# Fluent NHibernate Querying: Check for nullable column values

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nullreferenceexception, queryover

I have the following problem: I have a nullable column in my database table.
I want to be able to add a filter for it in my Where clause.
However, when the column is in fact null, I get an error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```
public class MyClass
{
     public virtual float? Id { get; set; }
}

// When querying:
...
MyClass myClass = null;
var query = GetCurrentSession().QueryOver<MyClass>(() => myClass);

// The following all give the same null reference error.
(1) query.Where(() => myClass.Id.ToString() == "...");
(2) query.Where(() => myClass.Id.Value.ToString() == "...");
(3) query.Where(() => myClass.Id != null && myClass.Id.ToString() == "...");
(4) query.Where(() => myClass.Id != null && myClass.Id.Value.ToString() == "...");
(5) query.Where(() => myClass.Id.HasValue && myClass.Id.ToString() == "...");
(6) query.Where(() => myClass.Id.HasValue && myClass.Id.Value.ToString() == "...");
```

A somewhat similar problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593292/fluent-nhibernate-query-where-nullable-int), but didn't help me out.

It looks like lazy evaluation within the Where clause doesn't seem to take place.
I get the feeling, I'm overlooking something very obvious here, however can't seem to find it.

**UPDATE:** Okay, so based on Novakov suggestion below, I was able to fix the nullable float comparison issue.
However, the same problem still remains for (other) string values. For example, I want to be able to do something like this, and the same exception keeps popping up, even if I check for null in the query.

```
query.WhereRestrictionOn(() => myClass.MyJoinedTable.MyField.ToLowerInvariant()).IsLike("%test%");
```

Comment: Have you tried simple ()=>myClass.Id == 0.5 ? I'm pretty sure that it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `QueryOver` syntax (see [16. QueryOver Queries](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover)) should look like this:

I. nullable property

```
query.Where(() => myClass.Id == searchedValue)
```

Does not matter, that the property is nullable. The above statement will take only these rows, which do have value in DB and which value is equal to `searchedValue`

II. searching for string

```
MyJoinedTable myJoinedTable = null;

query
   ...
  .JoinQueryOver<MyJoinedTable>(() => myClass.MyJoinedTable, () => myJoinedTable)
  .WhereRestrictionOn(() => myJoined.Field)
      .IsInsensitiveLike("test", MatchMode.Anywhere);
```

Above we can see that we firstly join the MyJoinedTable using `JoinQueryOver` and then we use SQL `LOWER()` with built in NHiberante method `IsInsensitiveLike(")`